# Output not printing expected variable. Scanf() issue

Tags: c, printing, syntax, char, stdio

The integer and character code work seperately, but don't work together in the same code.

```
#include<stdio.h>
int main() {
    int base;
    char num1,num2,num3,num4;

    scanf("%i",&base);
    printf("%i\n",base);

    scanf("%c",&num1);
    scanf("%c",&num2);
    scanf("%c",&num3);
    scanf("%c",&num4);

    printf("%c",num1);

    return 0;
}
```

Input:

```
8
m n o p
```

Expected output:

```
8
m
```

Real output:

```
8
```

Answer (score 0):

My understanding is that when you are reading in the characters, it is taking whitespace instead of the actual number. To fix this, you can add a whitespace character in front of the `%c` like so:

```
#include<stdio.h>
int main() {
    int base;
    char num1,num2,num3,num4;

    scanf("%i",&base);
    printf("%i\n",base);

    scanf(" %c",&num1);
    scanf(" %c",&num2);
    scanf(" %c",&num3);
    scanf(" %c",&num4);

    printf("%c",num1);

    return 0;
}
```

Hope this helps!